# Python compiler skips an "if" satement

Tags: python

I'm still new to the python language and I need help with my simple program. My program seems to work just fine at first but later on, python seems to skip my "if" statements after "option1" and "option2", and somewhat directly proceeds to its invalid error, then exit, still new and I need help on this one or if anyone can suggest the best option, I will greatly appreciate it. I use python 3.9 by the way.

Here's my program:

```
redo = True
choice = "a" or "A"
choice2 = "b" or "B"


while redo == True:
    # Program Interface [ variables are written specifically to avoid errors.]
    print("=================== GEOMETRIC CALCULATOR ===================")
    print("                         *SHAPE*")
    print("(a) Cube")
    print("(b) Cylender")
    print("------------------------------------------------------------")
    option1 = (input("Please choose a shape (a/b): "))  # User input
    if option1 != choice or option1 != choice2:
        print("Invalid selection, please only choose the given selection")
        exit()
    else:
        print("An error has occurred.")
    print("------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("                      *OPEARATIONS*")
    print("(a) Volume")
    print("(b) Surface Area")
    print("------------------------------------------------------------")
    option2 = input("Please choose an operation (a/b): ")  # User input
    if option2 != choice or option2 != choice2:
        print("Invalid selection, please only choose the given selection")
        exit()
    else:
        print("An error has occurred.")
        # Defining Functions
    def cubeVolume(a):
        v = float(a * a * a)  # Volume (Cube)
        return v
    def cubeSurfaceArea(a):
        sa = float(6 * (a * a))  # Surface Area (Cube)
        return sa
    def cylinderVolume(r, h):
        cv = float(3.1415 * (r * r) * h)  # Cylinder Volume
        return cv
    def cylinderSurfaceArea(r, h):
        cSA = (2 * 3.1415 * r * h) + (2 * 3.1415 * (r * r))  # Cylinder Surface Area
        return cSA
    # result selection program [ variables are written specifically to avoid errors.]
    try:
        if (option1 == "a" or option1 == "A") and (option2 == "a" or option2 == "A"):
            sidevalue1 = float(input("Enter side value: "))
            print("The volume of the cube is " + str(cubeVolume(sidevalue1)))
        elif (option1 == "a" or option1 == "A") and (option2 == "b" or option2 == "B"):
            sidevalue2 = float(input("Enter side value: "))
            print("The surface area of the cube is " + str(cubeSurfaceArea(sidevalue2)))
        elif (option1 == "b" or option1 == "B") and (option2 == "a" or option2 == "A"):
            radius1 = float(input("Enter radius value: "))
            height1 = float(input("Enter height value: "))
            print("The volume of the cylinder is " + str(cylinderVolume(radius1, height1)))
        elif (option1 == "b" or option1 == "B") and (option2 == "b" or option2 == "B"):
            radius2 = float(input("Enter radius value: "))
            height2 = float(input("Enter height value: "))
            print("The surface area of the cylinder is " + str(cylinderSurfaceArea(radius2, height2)))
    except:
        print("Invalid! Please input only a numerical value.")
        exit()
    # Asking the to try again
    reconf = input("Would you like to try again? (y/n): ")
    if reconf == "y" or reconf == "Y":
        redo = True
    elif reconf == "n" or reconf == "N":
        redo = False
    else:
        print("Error! Choose only from the given options.")
        exit()
```

Comment: Please check to see what the values in `option1` and `option2` actually are.

Comment: Just a tip for the future: an `if` will never be simply "skipped". If its body doesn't run, the condition is false (or the `if` was never reached in the first place). Double check the data in cases like this, and make sure that the `if` is being reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if option1 != choice or option1 != choice2` will be true for ANY value of option1. The same for option2.

You can check this:

```py
option1 = input("Please choose a shape (a/b): ")  # User input
if option1 != choice or option1 != choice2:
   print(option1 != choice or option1 != choice2)  # x or y
   # print("x:", option1 != choice)
   # print("y:", option1 != choice2)
   print("Invalid selection, please only choose the given selection")
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#booleans):

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates x; if x is true, its value
> is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
> returned.

**Output cases**:

x is false, y is true

```sh
Please choose a shape (a/b): a
True
Invalid selection, please only choose the given selection
```

x is true, y is false

```sh
Please choose a shape (a/b): b
True
Invalid selection, please only choose the given selection
```

x is true, y is true

```sh
Please choose a shape (a/b): c
True
Invalid selection, please only choose the given selection
```

**Solution**:

You can organize the valid options into one list...

```py
choices = ["a", "A", "b", "B"]
```

and validate user input as shown below:

```py
option1 = input("Please choose a shape (a/b): ")  # User input
if option1 not in choices:
    print("Invalid selection, please only choose the given selection")
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that unless choice and choice2 are identical,

```py
if option2 != choice or option2 != choice2:
```

is always true. option2 is indeed going to be not equal to one of these. Using `and` instead of `or` would probably be what you intended.